# TYPO3 - How do you add a mail form to all pages?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Using Default TS (form) in TYPO3 (7.2.0) standard template engine, how do I create a mail form and have it appear on all pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete, you should give us more details about used [TYPO3](https://typo3.org/about/the-brand/style-guide/the-typo3-spelling/) (**not** Typo3) version, used template engine, etc...

Anyway universal recipe is:

1. Create content element with mail form.
2. According to template engine that you are using use [`CONTENT`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) or [`RECORDS`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html) cObj to pass this record into your marker/subpart/Fluid's var

Comment: I am a beginner at this, but I am working on several installations of TYPO3 with different versions. All using the standard template engine.
The solution I have found based on what you said is:
myform = RECORDS
myform {
  tables = tt_content
  source = 159
}